# Git Connection Refused error

Tags: bitbucket-server

I have checked server proxy setting and everything is fine but when I try to take clone and push the code in bitbucket through the source tree, eclipse or git-bash I am facing below error.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v origin master:master

fatal: unable to access 'http://Asha.Ahirwar@code.airtelworld.in:7990/bitbucket/scm/test/ankush.git/': Failed to connect to code.airtelworld.in port 7990: Connection refused
```

Comment: Please help its critical issue.....